# Run File after 7zip self extracting zip file Not working

Tags: 7zip

I can not get a self extracting zip file to execute a command after it is extracted, My `config.txt` looks like this

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
GUIMode="2"
RunProgram="LogMeIn.msi"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

( Only the 4 lines, not extra lines before or after ), It is encoded with UTF8 ( I have tried it Standard and Without BOM )

I created the `.7z` using the default compression, and by this command:

```
copy /b "C:\program Files\7-zip\7zCon.sfx" + config.txt + archive.7z install.exe
```

When I run the `install.exe` it extracts `LogMeIn.msi` but does not actually run it. Am I missing something? I have looked at every tutorial and they all say to do the same thing

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue, I needed the 7zip 7zsd_extra and I used the 7zsd_All.sfx and it worked prefict